# Why is it better to drink room temperature water instead of cold water?

Tags: human-biology

My teacher told me that drinking water that is room temperature is better for you then drinking cold water, but she did not tell me why that is. I want to know because I often drink cold water (with ice), because I can't stand water that is room temperature or warm.

Comment: Are we even sure this is true? [Countervailing attitudes](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/cold-water-therapy/) to cold water exist.

Comment: Drink warm water, because [calves choose the same](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022030211002256)! ;-) I don't think it has any significant effect on your health. You may get easier sore throat if you drink too cold, but that's all...

Comment: I think this would better fit to skeptics.sx.

Comment: I don't there is much difference. The only reason I can think of is that cold water lowers your temperature and therefore your body needs more energy.

Comment: better fitted for skeptics SE

Comment: http://www.jissn.com/content/pdf/1550-2783-9-44.pdf - this link may answer your q....partially, though...

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher was passing on a myth.

This false belief might be related to the equally false belief that hot exerted horses should not be fed cold water. It could also be down to someone downing a big glass of ice-cold water in one go as a child, get a brief stomach ache and spin a health-advice on it.